# Adding child/parent links to a flat XML file in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a flat xml document. The nodes do contain information indicating if it is a parent or child node and are in sequential order where the child nodes follow their parent nodes. I need an XSLT file to convert the input xml into an xml file where the child nodes have a link back to their parent nodes.

Input XML file:

```
<items>
    <item type="a">
        <value ID="11111" relation="parent"></value>
    </item>
    <item type="b">
        <value ID="22222" relation="child"></value>
    </item>
    <item type="b">
        <value ID="33333" relation="child"></value>
    </item>
    <item type="a">
        <value ID="44444" relation="parent"></value>
    </item>
    <item type="b">
        <value ID="55555" relation="child"></value>
    </item>
    <item type="a">
        <value ID="66666" relation="parent"></value>
    </item>
    <item type="a">
        <value ID="77777" relation="parent"></value>
    </item>
    <item type="b">
        <value ID="88888" relation="child"></value>
    </item>
    <item type="b">
        <value ID="99999" relation="child"></value>
    </item>
    <item type="b">
        <value ID="00000" relation="child"></value>
    </item>
</items>
```

I want to convert it into:

```
<items>
<item>
    <itemType>a</itemType>
    <itemID>11111</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>parent</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID />
</item>
<item>
    <itemType>b</itemType>
    <itemID>22222</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>child</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID>insert parent ID here</itemParentID>
</item>
<item>
    <itemType>b</itemType>
    <itemID>33333</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>child</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID>insert parent ID here</itemParentID>
</item>
<item>
    <itemType>a</itemType>
    <itemID>44444</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>parent</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID />
</item>
<item>
    <itemType>b</itemType>
    <itemID>55555</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>child</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID>insert parent ID here</itemParentID>
</item>
<item>
    <itemType>a</itemType>
    <itemID>66666</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>parent</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID />
</item>
<item>
    <itemType>a</itemType>
    <itemID>77777</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>parent</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID />
</item>
<item>
    <itemType>b</itemType>
    <itemID>88888</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>child</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID>insert parent ID here</itemParentID>
</item>
<item>
    <itemType>b</itemType>
    <itemID>99999</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>child</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID>insert parent ID here</itemParentID>
</item>
<item>
    <itemType>b</itemType>
    <itemID>00000</itemID>
    <itemRelationship>child</itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID>insert parent ID here</itemParentID>
</item>
</items>
```

Where the “insert parent ID here” is replaced by the child’s node parent ID.

Here is my current xslt file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
     version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <items>
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <item>
                <xsl:variable name = "vCurrentItemType" select ="@type"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test = "$vCurrentItemType = 'a'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="DrawParent">
                            <xsl:with-param name = "pCurrentItem" select =  "current()"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="DrawChild">
                            <xsl:with-param name = "pCurrentItem" select = "current()"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </items>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name = "DrawParent">
    <xsl:param name = "pCurrentItem" />
    <itemType>
        <xsl:value-of select ="$pCurrentItem/@type"/>
    </itemType>
    <itemID>
        <xsl:value-of select ="$pCurrentItem/value/@ID"/>
    </itemID>
    <itemRelationship>
        <xsl:value-of select ="$pCurrentItem/value/@relation"/>
    </itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID></itemParentID>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name = "DrawChild">
    <xsl:param name = "pCurrentItem" />
    <itemType>
        <xsl:value-of select ="$pCurrentItem/@type"/>
    </itemType>
    <itemID>
        <xsl:value-of select ="$pCurrentItem/value/@ID"/>
    </itemID>
    <itemRelationship>
        <xsl:value-of select ="$pCurrentItem/value/@relation"/>
    </itemRelationship>
    <itemParentID>insert parent ID here</itemParentID>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression you want for your parent ID is this....

```
<xsl:value-of select="$pCurrentItem/preceding-sibling::item[@type='a'][1]/value/@ID" />
```

However, you may consider simplifying your XSLT to this, to avoid some code repetition....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="item">
       <item>
          <itemType>
              <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
          </itemType>
          <itemID>
              <xsl:value-of select="value/@ID"/>
          </itemID>
          <itemRelationship>
              <xsl:value-of select="value/@relation"/>
          </itemRelationship>
          <itemParentID>
              <xsl:if test="@type='b'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::item[@type='a'][1]/value/@ID" />                  
              </xsl:if>
          </itemParentID>
       </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```